# Can I change java application heap size on my android smartphone?

Tags: java, android, heap-memory

I'm currently using a `Samsung Galaxy A20s` with a total of 2790MB ram.

the phone was originally developed for `Android 9.0 Pie` and it has been getting upgrades and I'm currently on `Android 11 Honeycomb` which is a good thing but the hardware on the phone can't keep up. my ram is always almost full and according to `Droid Info` app my Java Heap size is 192MB !!!. that's way too much!!

is there any way to reduce the heap size on my smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can root your smartphone and get almost full access for example remove factory installed apps, overclock your CPU, increase RAM etc. But rooting will void the warranty and also if your smartphone is uncommon, do it at your own risk !

**Read more about it here**

https://www.xda-developers.com/root/

Comment: 1. need app set largeHeap = true in AndroidManifest.xml
2. root.  change /system/build.prop